AuthenticationFailed error while trying to use safe download workflow artifact
Trying to run below workflow but getting:
Error:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Error>
  <Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code>
  <Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the 
    value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the 
    signature.
    RequestId:b37a6424-701e-004c-55dc-da07c1000000
    Time:2024-07-20T19:39:41.7435261Z
  </Message>
</Error>

Workflow:
name: check actions
run-name: check actions

on: 
    workflow_dispatch:
    push:

jobs:
  artifacts:
    name: Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
        - name: use action
          uses: Legit-Labs/action-download-artifact@v2
          with:
            github_token: ${{ secrets.TOKEN }}
            workflow: artifact.yml
            path: ${{ github.workspace }}

        - run: ls -la


Did you intend to use secret with name TOKEN? Do you have it defined in your repo? Or is this a typo for secret.GITHUB_TOKEN?
